# i'm having a very complicated(by my standard) issue on baking

Tags: materials, uv, lighting, texture-baking, baking

i want to bake a whole scene of multiple object, i'm having quite a few issue with this.

first off this is my scene[image]

first issue, it has multiple object on it. do i have to bake every single one of them? or is there an easier way?(join and then uv unwrap or some sort while keeping the texture intact?)[image]

second, if i decide to bake them one by one, how do i handle the uv unwrap on the object without ruining the texture. like the road tiled texture
[image]

third, how do i bake an object with multiple material? do i have to put new image on every material? or is there an easier way(i know it has something to do with making a second uv map for baking, but thats about it, i have no idea how to use it on the node editor[image]
and last, why do my baked image always turns to black, even when i uv unwrapped it?( i create a second uv map for baking, smart uv unwrap it, i highlight it, and i highlight the new image, but it still came out black. what am i doing wrong?[image]

just a heads up, im still getting use with baking, i've seen the tutorial on baking before, but never actually put it to use until this project. so please have mercy on thy soul and explain to me like youre trying to explain to a person with half a brain cell. Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: hello, first off, do you really need to bake the texture?

Comment: yes i do, i have around 80 spot light on the scene, and the light stop working after 30 or so( stop emitting light), not counting the particle emitting from the top(im making it snow). when i rendered it, the light only lights up on the few first tenth frame, and then suddenly stops emitting lighting on the 30th frame when the particle starts showing(even the snow particle didnt show up on render). so this is a very heavy scene, and i need to lighten it up. it is a urban environment

Comment: You can duplicate your object in order to keep a safe version in a collection, then join all the objects, create a new unwrap for the whole object, and bake onto a new image.

Answer (score 1):

**Solutions:**

1st issue: if you don't use any addons that speed up baking workflows, then yes, you will need to proceed the bake for each. (if packing all uvs onto one meets your needs, then yes, you can do that)

2nd issue: You can try `Smart UV Project` if you need uv. If the bake is not necessary here, you can keep tiled texture material without any baking.

3rd issue: Place an `image texture` node referencing the same image file into every material you want

4th issue: Not proper bake settings, not the right active uv layer.

How to have one bake for all objects:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Ready

Comment: 1ST ISSUE : do i have to join them in that case? but if i join them, and smart uv unwrap them, wont that mess up the texture? unless i use a second uv? then how i do that with bakng? 2ND ISSUE: i did tried smart uv project, and it turn out just like in the picture. 3RD ISSUE : so i do have to put an image texture to every single material? do you happen to know if theres a way to unwrap everything in one image? i dont wanna use to much space for the blender file with a lot of image, its already 500mb. 4TH ISSUE, i tho i already did everything right? what am i missing ?

Comment: I will add video in a minute

Comment: thanks my friend, ill try this later, i'll let you know if it works :D